# JSON to Java: How to model lists of objects into generic object class whose object name from json is variable

Tags: java, json, jackson

Suppose I have the following JSON that I'm unable to alter as it's provided over a web feed by someone else. I want to parse this using Jackson to Java objects.

```
{
"2002": [
  {
    "d": "description",
    "t": "title"
  }
],
"2003": [
  {
    "d": "description",
    "t": "title"
  }
]
}
```

The data represents, say, a list of TV programmes with ids=2002, 2003 ...etc, and each programme has a description and title. I want to parse this data into a List of generic Programme classes, where each programme class has fields d and t. I don't want to have separate classes for 2002, 2003 etc objects. Bearing in mind, the 2002, 2003 etc ids are not known until runtime and can evolve over time, and could also be quite a long list of possible values.

Is it possible to model this as a list of generic programmes whose id field is equal to the name of the object name from the json string? In other words, I don't want this:

```
public class AllProgrammes {
  private List<com.example._2002> _2002;
  private List<com.example._2003> _2003;
  // getters and setters
}
```

but instead this should just contain `List<Programmes>`, and each programme object should have an id = 2002, or 2003, or whatever id it is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use Google Gson, you can do that this way:

Program.class

```
public class Program {
  private String id;
  private String title;
  private String description;

  public Program(String id, String title, String description) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("Program[id=%s, title=%s, description=%s]", this.id, this.title, this.description);
  }
}
```

ProgramsDeserializer.class

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class ProgramsDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<Program>> {
  @Override
  public List<Program> deserialize(JsonElement e, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException {
    List<Program> programs = new ArrayList<>(10);
    JsonObject root = e.getAsJsonObject();
    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : root.entrySet()) {
      String id = entry.getKey();
      String title = "";
      String description = "";
      JsonElement arrayElement = entry.getValue();
      if (arrayElement.isJsonArray()) {
        JsonArray array = arrayElement.getAsJsonArray();
        JsonElement objectElement = array.get(0);
        if (objectElement.isJsonObject()) {
          JsonObject object = objectElement.getAsJsonObject();
          title = object.get("t").getAsString();
          description = object.get("d").getAsString();
        }
      }
      programs.add(new Program(id, title, description));
    }
    return programs;
  }
}
```

GsonExample.class

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class GsonExample {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GsonExample.class.getName());
  private static final String JSON = 
    "{"
      + "\"2002\": ["
        + "{"
          + "\"d\": \"description\","
          + "\"t\": \"title\""
        + "}"
      + "],"
      + "\"2003\": ["
        + "{"
          + "\"d\": \"description\","
          + "\"t\": \"title\""
        + "}"
      + "]"
    + "}";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GsonExample e = new GsonExample();
    e.run();
  }

  private void run() {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Program>>(){}.getType();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(type, new ProgramsDeserializer());
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    List<Program> programs = gson.fromJson(JSON, type);
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "{0}", programs);
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Looks like my simple direct data binding wasn't sufficient for this, but having a custom deserializer looks to be a very flexible solution. I'm sure you can probably do something similar in jackson, but I'm happy to switch to google gson as none of my client code outside the parser relies on any specific concrete  json implementation.